# Error: The specified folder does not contain a Java platform

Tags: jdk, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 11 and JDK 11 on Ubuntu 16.4.  Why am I getting this error in the platform manager?

I also get "Broken Platform JDK 11 (Default)" in my project Libraries.

Comment: Is Java installed? `sudo apt-get install default-jre default-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Java on your machine **and** have the path to the installation in the $PATH variable. I suggest using apt to install openjdk/openjre. It will automatically do everything for you. You might want to find out whether you need to install a specific version of Java, due to your specific hardware/software requirements.

Comment: I have done all that.  The JDK is in /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64.  I also added that folder in the $PATH variable.  Still a problem.

Comment: The program that needs the Java platform actually looks for a file with a specific name. Maybe your version of openjdk has that file with a different name. I suggest reading the docs of Netbeans and openjdk to find out if  the needed file has a correct name. If everything is fine, then it's most likely a bug.